# What decision tree algorithm does Orange3 implement?

Tags: orange

I'm just wondering roughly what decision tree algorithm orange3 implements in the tree widget?

What measure of purity does it deploy?

Answer (score 2):

> Tree is a simple algorithm that splits the data into nodes by class purity. It is a precursor to **Random Forest**

https://docs.biolab.si//3/visual-programming/widgets/model/tree.html

This should be the related source code:
https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/master/Orange/modelling/randomforest.py

Comment: Thanks! By the looks of it they are using their own method for calculating purity rather than something entropy based etc?

Comment: Well I guess you need to dig a bit deeper to find that out. It looks like they even implement some c modules. Hard too tell what's exactly behind it